# How to use rsplit with None vaules in Python?

Tags: python

At my Python application, I want to get a specific value from a list:

```
rating_unit_value = clean_result['format']['tags'].get('itunextc', None).rsplit('|', 3)[0]
```

The Problem here is that if 'itunextc' does not exist, it should return None instead, where rsplit can't work with a None value. So, how can I apply the rsplit only if 'itunextc' exists? Of course this can be done with an if else statement or try except, but is this really the only way to go ?

Something like this pseudocode would be cool:

```
rating_unit_value = clean_result['format']['tags'].get('itunextc'.rsplit('|', 3)[0], None)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use a try except block.

Comment: Same lvl of ugliness I guess as the if else clause ^^. But yes it would work, sure!

Comment: What value would you want assigned to rating_unit_value if itunextc doesn't exist?

Comment: Simply None. It is an optional field at my Database in the end.

Comment: what if you use another default instead of None if the field doesn't exist? e.g. `""` instead of `None` in the call to `get`?

Comment: Would an empty string suffice instead of `None`? If so you could replace `None` in the `get` with `''`

Comment: That would imply that I have to set a rating value where None is given by the original Author of the object I'm working on here. So sadly not a solution. But thanks for this Idea. I sadly can't do any guessing here or say the value is a random one.

Comment: What does the `itunextc` string look like?

Comment: @Nick Note that `None` (absence of a value) usually translates to `null` in a database, which is definitely different than an empty string (empty value). Essentially the same in Python, even if they both evaluate to `False` in an if-clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an assignment expression and a conditional expression:

```
rating_unit_value = val.rsplit('|', 3)[0] if (val := clean_result['format']['tags'].get('itunextc')) else None
```

Whether that is clearer (or generally "better") than an if-else or a try-except, is really in the eye of the beholder.

---

Simplified example:

```
>>> a = dict(b='1|1')
>>> e = val.split('|') if (val := a.get('c')) else None
>>> print(e)
None
>>> e = val.split('|') if (val := a.get('b')) else None
>>> e
['1', '1']
```

Comment: Nice idea. Of course, no need to explicitly pass None as the 2nd parameter to *get()* as it's the default

Comment: Uuuh, well, that's kinda sexy! Just implemented this to try, works like a charm!
Thanks for your answere

Comment: @AlbertWinestein Thanks, good point. I probably got "blinded" by the code in the question.

Comment: @PeterHammi But let me know in a year time if you can still understand that one-line of code, without staring at it for more than a minute.

Comment: Basically I do, but I currently don't understand what "val" is exactly for or what it does same goes for ":=" but it has to be part of the conditional expression

Comment: `val` is a temporary variable. The `:=`, also known as the the walrus operator, assigns *and* returns a value. So the assignment can immediately be evaluated (in this case, by the `if` statement). But, it is *not* part (i.e. essential to) the conditional expression. Search around for for more info about it. But I suggest to limit its usage: it rarely has an actual use, and mostly saves about one line of code (at the expense of confusion; for example, you don't even understand it yet, while an if-else, you would understand).